# How to pass two parameters using node.js?

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have passed two params from client to express endpoint it gives me results on my local machine but when i deploy to linux server its not working no errors and no response ? Do you think it could be params issue?

```
 // client.js

 getServerSearch: function(str, strEnv) {
   return $http.get("/serverSearch?searchTxt=" + str + '&searchEnv=' + strEnv);
 }

 // server.js

 app.get('/serverSearch', function(req, res) {

   var searchTxt = req.query.searchTxt;

   var searchEnv = req.query.searchEnv;

   searchFileService.readFile(searchTxt, searchEnv, function(lines, err) {

     console.log('Logs', lines);

     if (err)
       return res.send();

     res.json(lines);
   });

   console.log('Search text', searchTxt);
 });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem, but you should avoid case sensitivity in URL and parameters. Try converting all of those to lower case.

Comment: Have ever you checked for CORS issue?